# Gráfico de barras python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics

Opa galera, tudo bem? Essa é minha primeira publicação aqui,desculpa se eu cometer algum erro... Estou começando agora a aprender a programar em Python, e preciso de uma ajudinha...
Os axis do meu gráfico estão se sobrepondo. Como faço pra concertar?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a função `xticks` para rotacionar os textos do eixo x, passando o grau de inclinação como parâmetro `rotation`.

Exemplo rotacionando 45°:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(['teste 1', 'teste 2', 'teste 3'], [20, 30, 50])
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

[image: labels rotacionadas]

[Documentação da função](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)

Comment: Deu certo! obrigado